# Leaflet: Moving the map doesn't move the icons with it, instead the icons stay fixed to the same position on the page

Tags: leaflet

Moving the map doesn't move the icons with it, instead the icons stay fixed to the same position on the page.

My icons get added to the correct latitude and longitude on my map. However, when I drag the map, the icons stay fixed on the same position on the page and are no longer being displayed at the correct latitude and longitude.

```
let sMap;
let ciLayer;
let neutralMarkers = [];
let gVesselIcons = {};
let numOfVessels = 0;
let ROI;

let nwLat;
let nwLon;
let seLat;
let seLon;

window.indexedDB =
  window.indexedDB ||
  window.mozIndexedDB ||
  window.webkitIndexedDB ||
  window.msIndexedDB;

//prefixes of window.IDB objects
window.IDBTransaction =
  window.IDBTransaction ||
  window.webkitittIDBTransaction ||
  window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange =
  window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;

let db;
const [dbPromise, dbResolve, dbReject] = (() => {
  let resolve, reject;
  return [
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
      resolve = res;
      reject = rej;
    }),
    resolve,
    reject
  ];
})();
let dbGSTSStore = window.indexedDB.open('GSTSStore', 1);
let dbVessels;
let dbTransactions;
let dbMessages;

dbGSTSStore.onerror = function(event) {
  dbReject();
  console.log('error: ');
};
dbGSTSStore.onsuccess = function(event) {
  dbResolve();
  db = dbGSTSStore.result;
};

dbGSTSStore.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  const db = event.target.result;
  dbVessels = db.createObjectStore('vessels', {
    keyPath: 'mmsi'
  });
  dbMessages = db.createObjectStore('messages', {
    keyPath: 'id'
  });
  dbTransactions = db.createObjectStore('transactions', {
    keyPath: 'id'
  });
};


async function InitializeSimple(
  pBuildNumber,
  pSysPersonId,
  pSysOrganizationId
){

  await GetOrganizationPrefs(pSysOrganizationId);
  await GetPersonPrefs(pSysPersonId);
  SetLabelText('lblBuildNumber', `Build: ${pBuildNumber}`);
  dragElement(document.getElementById("vessel-info"));

  nwLat = gOrganizationPrefs.roinwse.nwlat || gPersonPrefs.aoi.nwlat;
  nwLon = gOrganizationPrefs.roinwse.nwlon || gPersonPrefs.aoi.nwlon;
  seLat = gOrganizationPrefs.roinwse.selat || gPersonPrefs.aoi.selat;
  seLon = gOrganizationPrefs.roinwse.selon || gPersonPrefs.aoi.selon;
  
  try {
    sMap = L.map('map-content', {
      fullscreenControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      zoom: 6,
      attributionControl: false,
      preferCanvas: true
    }).setView([19, 55]);

    ciLayer = L.canvasIconLayer({}).addTo(sMap);

    L.tileLayer(MapUrl[0], {
      attribution: MapAttribution[0],
      zoom: 5,
      minZoom: 4,
      maxNativeZoom: 13,
      maxZoom: 20
    }).addTo(sMap);
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.log("error initializing map\n");
  }
  
  // SetVesselUpdate();
  if(gOrganizationPrefs) await SetROI(gOrganizationPrefs.roinwse);
  else await SetROI(gPersonPrefs.aoi);
  
  await CreateNeutralLayer();
}

function SetLabelText(pLabel, pText) {
  const lLabel = document.getElementById(pLabel);
  if (lLabel !== undefined) lLabel.textContent = pText;
}

function CreateNeutralLayer(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const lTransaction = db.transaction(['vessels'], 'readonly');
      let vessels = lTransaction.objectStore('vessels');

      const countRequest = vessels.count();
      countRequest.onsuccess = function() {
        numOfVessels = countRequest.result;
      }
      
      vessels.openCursor().onsuccess = function(e) {
        let cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor !== null) {
          let value = cursor.value;
          let latitude = value.lat;
          let longitude = value.lon;
          let canInclude = checkROIBoundaries(latitude, longitude);

          if (canInclude && cursor.value !== undefined) {
            AddToLayers(cursor.value);
          }
          cursor.continue();
        }
      }
      resolve('OK');
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log("error is: ", err, "\n");
      reject({ error: err, function: 'CreateNeutralLayer()'});
    }
  });
}


function AddToLayers(vessel) {
  
  let vesselRotationDegree = vessel.headingdegree.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  if (vesselRotationDegree == '32') vesselRotationDegree = '00';

  let vesselIconType = 'type-3';
  let gBaseRiskIconURL = `./public/img/vessel/${vesselIconType}/vessel-`;
  let gBaseRiskNeutralUrl = `${gBaseRiskIconURL}neutral-`;

  var vIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: `${gBaseRiskNeutralUrl}${vesselRotationDegree}.svg`,
    iconSize: [24, 24],
    iconAnchor: [24, 24]
  });

  const marker = L.marker([vessel.lat, vessel.lon], { icon: vIcon});
  marker.properties = {
    vesselname: vessel.shipname,
    mmsi: vessel.mmsi,
    imo: vessel.imo,
    lat: vessel.lat,
    lon: vessel.lon,
    datetime: vessel.received_time,
    heading: vessel.hdg,
    sog: vessel.sog,
    shiptype_descr: vessel.shiptype_descr,
    last_positional_update: vessel.last_updated
  };

  marker.bindPopup(popupNeutralMarker, {
    maxWidth: 392,
    className: `map-info`
  });
  neutralMarkers.push(marker);
  
  if (neutralMarkers.length >= numOfVessels) {
    ciLayer.addLayers(neutralMarkers);
    const vesselsInROI = document.getElementById('vessels-in-roi');
    vesselsInROI.innerHTML = numOfVessels;
  }
}


function checkROIBoundaries(latitude, longitude) {
  let canInclude = false;

  const lLatOK =
    latitude >= Math.min(nwLat, seLat) &&
    latitude <= Math.max(nwLat, seLat);

  const lLonOK =
    longitude >= Math.min(nwLon, seLon) &&
    longitude <= Math.max(nwLon, seLon);
            
  if (lLatOK && lLonOK) canInclude = true;
  else numOfVessels--;

  return canInclude;
}


function SetROI(pROI) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      if (pROI.nwlat + pROI.nwlon + pROI.selat + pROI.selon === 0) return;

      const defaultBoundaryStyle = {
        color: 'blue',
        fillColor: 'lightblue',
        fillOpacity: 0.2
      }

      ROI = new L.rectangle(
        [
          [pROI.selat, pROI.selon],
          [pROI.nwlat, pROI.selon],
          [pROI.selat, pROI.selon],
          [pROI.selat, pROI.nwlon]
        ],
        defaultBoundaryStyle
      )

      sMap.addLayer(ROI, true);
      // Center ROI
      sMap.fitBounds([
        [gOrganizationPrefs.roinwse.nwlat, gOrganizationPrefs.roinwse.nwlon],
        [gOrganizationPrefs.roinwse.selat, gOrganizationPrefs.roinwse.selon]
      ]);
      resolve('OK');
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log("error is: ", err, "\n");
      reject({ error: err, function: 'SetROI'});
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make your code minimal.

Comment: Even more important than _minimal_ (however this is defined), make it reproducible.